# How to extract paragraphs from text/pdf using nltk?

Tags: nlp, nltk

I am wanting to extract paragraphs from a big text file , basic idea is to extract each section of a pdf , I know the following :
Each section begins with a number like 7.1 , 7.2 etc , So I want to extract all the text before 7.2 that would belong to 7.1 , similarly if I extract all the text before first occurrence of world 7.3 , and subtract 7-1 , it would give me 7.2 . So is there a way to do that in nltk ?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: @DeepanRaj No unfortunately I havn't.